# Obtain Object From Global Environment and Slice It Like a Dataframe

Tags: r

I foresee this question will have to be heavily edited by a more experienced R user as I'm unsure of the right terminologies to use.

Here is a reproducible dataframe. Would it be possible to obtain the object from global environment and slice it like a normal dataframe?

```
df1 <- data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "Orange", "Pear"), location = c("Japan", "China", "Nigeria"), price = c(32,53,12))

df1
   fruit location price
1  apple    Japan    32
2 Orange    China    53
3   Pear  Nigeria    12
```

Obtaining list of objects in global environment

```
allobj <- ls()
allobj[1]
"df1"
```

I understand that by using the `noquote` function, it returns the name of the object, which in this case is `df1` - the name of my dataframe.

How do I treat this output as a named dataframe, in a base R slice? For instance,

```
(noquote(allobj[1]))[,1] #subset out only the 'fruit' column.
```

The above returns the error:

> Error in unclass(x)[...] : incorrect number of dimensions

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: do `df2 <- get(obj[1])` and then extract the first column `df2[, 1]`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible to not have the assignment? Cos I intend to pass the object name i.e. df1 through a function

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get` and then subset the first column

```
get(obj[1])[1]

#   fruit
#1  apple
#2 Orange
#3   Pear
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same with small edit, please find it below and let me know if it suits

```
df1 <- data.frame(fruit=c("apple", "Orange", "Pear"), location = c("Japan", "China", "Nigeria"), price = c(32,53,12))

objs = ls()

get(objs[1])[,1] # for values as a vector
[1] apple  Orange Pear  
Levels: apple Orange Pear

get(objs[1])[1] #for column subset
   fruit
1  apple
2 Orange
3   Pear
```